# Reinstalling windows from scratch

Tags: windows, partitioning, security, dualboot

I've just purchased a new PC. As expected, it came with a somewhat *preinstalled* windows (I wonder how that works, since it seems to go through the normal installation process, but ends up with bloatware...).

I don't trust what they have done in that installation process, whether installing bloatware or spyware that I don't need, which takes up resources and cause a security (privacy, at least) concern.

I'd like to reinstall it from scratch. I have searched on the net but haven't found a clear tutorial on how to do that with w11.

It came with 4 partitions, the main C: one, ESP (240MB), winretools (1GB), dellsupport (1.5GB), a image recovery partition of 20GB, and 15MB unallocated for whatever reason.

Should I delete all of that and reinstall windows on the whole drive, or should I keep some of those partitions, and if so, how / why ?

Do I need to save some data, such as the product key, before reinstalling it all ?

Are there any post-installation steps, such as telling w11 that my drive is a ssd and doesn't need partitioning, that might have been done by dell by all of that bloatware, and that I would want to reproduce ?

I also want to dual boot with linux on that computer. Should I start with reinstalling windows, and then adding linux, or should it be the other way around ?

Thanks

Comment: If you do that you're just going to end up going back to Dell for all their hardware-specific drivers etc. Just uninstall the stuff you don't want. i'm pretty sure if a company the size of Dell was spying on people, it would be known by now… & the consequent court case, bankruptcy & demise would be front page news.

Answer (score 0):

Dell has preinstalled on your computer drivers that are absolutely
required and some useful support software.
Unfortunately, it also installed  some trial versions of
commercial products.

You would do better not to do a clean reinstall of Windows,
since that would lose you the good stuff together with the bad,
and you could end up with only a partially-functional computer.
You will then need to chase down and install the software that
you're missing.

You may uninstall without a problem any trialware software, and especially
the McAfee Antivirus (Windows Defender is more than good enough).
Games are also fair game.

You should leave Dell Support Assist, since it will frequently scan
your computer and alert you to new updates for drivers and BIOS, and
do so much before Windows Update does. Support Assist is mostly
useful only during the warranty period, and will become less
functional once this runs out.

You should leave alone the other partitions. They are small enough,
and they contain software you will need for recovering the computer
in case of a catastrophic error of Windows.

Comment: As @harrymc states, it's best to remove bloatware. Two suggestions: 1. **Make a full disk image** before making changes, not only to recover from errors, but to make it easier to sell or donate the machine at a later date. 2. There are useful tools to remove bloatware and unwanted Windows apps, such as Windows Decrapifier (https://github.com/n1snt/Windows-Decrapifier), O&O AppBuster (https://www.oo-software.com/en/ooappbuster) and mny others: https://alternativeto.net/software/pc-decrapifier/

Comment: Thanks for answering. As I said, I plan to mainly use this new computer with linux (dual boot), so I wouldn't get all these special configs anyway. I just want to do the same with windows. Is there a way I can find out what's been done (drivers, ...) over a regular installation?